# how to update a column in db with keeping the old content in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I need to update a column with keeping the current content in Laravel using eloquent. I am using the following code to update

```
        $invoice = Invoice::find($request->input('session_cat_invoice'));
        $invoice->note = $request->input('invoice_note');
        $invoice->save();
```

column in DB before the update

> test1

column in DB after the update using my code

> test2

and that we I don't want, what I need is the following

> test1 test2

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find($request->input('session_cat_invoice'));
$invoice->note = $invoice->note . ' ' . $request->input('invoice_note');
$invoice->save();
```

Comment: `+` isn't the concatenation operator in **PHP**. `$invoice->note . ' ' . $request->input('invoice_note');`